# Polyline FLAT Buffer: How to create coverage beyond ends of line? (VISUAL REQUEST)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, buffer, visualisation

To clarify, if we consider the output of a buffer when choosing FLAT or ROUND.
[image: Buffer Comparison]

I'm wondering if there is a way to extend the area coverage of the FLAT type beyond the ends of the line with a similar (I don't need exact) length.

My reasons for asking are strictly visual and not having to manually reshape each buffer (as there are many).

Answer (score 0):

Create round buffers, convert them to lines and merge with original:

[image]

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(in_layer="w_Buffer", overlap_type="INTERSECT", select_features="ORIGINAL", search_distance="", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", invert_spatial_relationship="NOT_INVERT")
arcpy.ExtendLine_edit(in_features="w_Buffer", length="2.1 Meters", extend_to="EXTENSION")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(in_layer="w_Buffer", overlap_type="INTERSECT", select_features="ORIGINAL", search_distance="", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", invert_spatial_relationship="NOT_INVERT")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features="w_Buffer", out_feature_class="in_memory/flat", buffer_distance_or_field="1.5 Meters", line_side="FULL", line_end_type="FLAT", dissolve_option="NONE", dissolve_field="", method="PLANAR")
```

[image]